# Font for the interpretation line of a barcode

Tags: fonts, barcode, zebra-printers, zpl

How can I know which (default) font is used when the **interpretation line** of a barcode is printed using this ZPL command:

```
^BCN,40,Y,N,N,A
```

I would like to use the same font for the other fields...

When I know which font is used, I intend to use the ZPL `^A` command to apply it to the other fields.

Comment: not-so-silly question: did you contact Zebra to ask them?

Comment: No, I haven't. I think - by visual comparison - that this is the D font.

Comment: in that case I'd strongly recommend contacting them with this question and if they get back to you, either you'll have more information to put in your post (e.g. "I asked Zebra but they couldn't tell me") or you'll have effectively answered it by doing the necessary research yourself =)

Answer (score 0):

In the [Zebra ZPL II Programming Giude](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) in the section of the `^BC` command it is explained how one can use different font settings for the interpretation line using the `^A` command (firmware x.11.x or higher required):

```
^XA
^FO50,200
^A0N,40,30^BCN,150,Y,N,Y
^FD>;>80012345123451234512^FS
^XZ
```

Since you don't have one specified in your example, the default `^CF` font is used, as stated in the section of the `^A` command.

If you also have no `^CF` command in your ZPL code, then default font A is used!